# Finding formula for sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

Find an explicit formula for a sequence of the form $a_1$​, $a_2$​, $a_3$​,… with the initial terms given below. $\frac{1}{5}$, -1, $\frac{1}{6}$, -$\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{1}{7}$, -$\frac{1}{3}$, $\frac{1}{8}$, -$\frac{1}{4}$, $\frac{1}{9}$, -$\frac{1}{5}$, $\frac{1}{10}$, -$\frac{1}{6}$

I've figured for even numbers that $a_{even} = \frac{(-1)^{(n-1)}}{(n/2)}$

and that for odd numbers $a_{odd} = \frac{(-1)^{(n-1)}}{n + \frac{9-n}{2}}$

but can not get how to write a formula to describe any $a_n$

Answer (score 1):

The sequence with entries $a(n)$ for $n$ even and $b(n)$ for $n$ odd is

$$ \frac{1 + (-1)^n}{2} a(n) + \frac{1 - (-1)^n}{2} b(n) $$

Comment: When I get the same answer as Robert Israel I know that I am right.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

If
$a_{2n}=b_n$
and
$a_{2n+1}=c_n$
then
$a_n
=\frac12((-1)^{n}+1)b_{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}
+(1-(-1)^{n})c_{\lfloor n/2\rfloor})
$
because
$(-1)^{n}+1$
is 2 for even $n$
and 0 for odd $n$
while
$1-(-1)^{n}$
is 2 for odd $n$
and 0 for even $n$.

To check,
substituting
$2n$ and $2n+1$ for $n$,
this gives

$\begin{array}\\
a_{2n}
&=\frac12((-1)^{2n}+1)b_{\lfloor (2n)/2\rfloor}
+(1-(-1)^{2n})c_{\lfloor (2n)/2\rfloor})\\
&=\frac12(2b_{n})\\
&=b_{n}\\
\text{and}\\
a_{2n+1}
&=\frac12((-1)^{2n+1}+1)b_{\lfloor (2n+1)/2\rfloor}
+(1-(-1)^{2n+1})c_{\lfloor (2n+1)/2\rfloor})\\
&=\frac12(2c_{n})\\
&=c_n\\\end{array}
$